# How to insert the data into sqlite

Tags: objective-c

I am working on iPhone application and getting response from server and i parse the response string  using JSON Parser it returns the dictionary. now i am not under stand how to use the data because it is came with back slash, i have print the data on console  i am sending this related image please check the image give a solution to me.  i am working on this problem from the last 6hrs onwards. please give me solution.!

```
 (
        "{\"category_id\":\"1\", \"category_name\":\"BEVERAGES\", \"image_id\":\"6\"}",
        "{\"category_id\":\"1\", \"category_name\":\"BEVERAGES\", \"image_id\":\"7\"}",
        "{\"category_id\":\"3\", \"category_name\":\"BREAKFAST\", \"image_id\":\"5\"}",
        "{\"category_id\":\"3\", \"category_name\":\"BREAKFAST\", \"image_id\":\"6\"}",
        "{\"category_id\":\"4\", \"category_name\":\"ALA CARTE\", \"image_id\":\"2\"}
    ),
        (
        "{\"subcategory_id\":\"1\",\"category_id\":\"3\", \"subcategory_name\":\"COMBOS\", \"image_id\":\"\"}",
        "{\"subcategory_id\":\"2\",\"category_id\":\"3\", \"subcategory_name\":\"OMELETES\", \"image_id\":\"\"}",
        "{\"subcategory_id\":\"3\",\"category_id\":\"3\", \"subcategory_name\":\"GRIDDLES\", \"image_id\":\"\"}"
    ),
```

Comment: Don't include code as images.  Copy/paste into your question, making sure it's indented 4 spaces so it's formatted as code.  (The `{}` button over the edit window will do the indent for you.)

Comment: (What you have is "embedded JSON".  Each line in the array is a JSON string that needs to be given another trip through NSJSONSerialization to fully decode.)

Comment: (And the outermost two structure layers are arrays, not dictionaries.)

Answer (score 0):

```
NSError* error = nil;
NSArray* jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];
if (jsonArray == nil) {
    NSLog(@"Error getting jsonArray: %@", error);
    // Handle error condition
}
NSArray* categoryArray = jsonArray[0];
for (NSString* innerJson in categoryArray) {
    NSData* innerJsonData = [innerJson dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary* innerDict = [[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:innerJsonData options:0 error:&error];
    if (innerDict == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Error getting innerDict: %@", error);
        // Handle error condition
    }    
    NSString* category_id = innerDict[@"category_id"];
    // etc
}
// Repeat for subcategoryArray = jsonArray[1]
```